# JMeter - Variable set in jsr 223 preprocessor is not available within while controller

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

Inside the Thread Group, I have "jsr 223 preprocessor" where I am setting variable like this -

```
List<String> EDPResultList = new ArrayList();
vars.putObject("EDPResultList",EDPResultList);
```

Then inside the while controller, I have an "HTTP Request Sampler". For processing the response, I have added a "jsr 223  postprocessor" where I am trying to access the object like this -

```
Object resObj = vars.getObject("EDPResultList");
```

I am getting the exception -

"ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor For Initial Get
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: EDPResultList for class: Script238
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]"

How can I define a list which I can user throughout my "Thread Group" and for multiple iterations of "While Controller".

Comment: I think the exception thrown in different code, do you have other code using `EDPResultList` ?

Answer (score 0):

To work with ArrayList in JMeter use the following approach:

1. Test Plan will look like this, first Sampler has JSR223 Pre Processor which initialize the ArrayList. While Controller has second Sampler with JSR223 Post Processor which access the ArrayList.
   [image]
2. JSR223 Pre Processor inside first Sampler. Put the following code in script area

   ```
   import java.util.List;

   List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

   list.add("John");
   list.add("Peter");
   list.add("Parkar");

   vars.putObject("List",list);
   ```

   [image]
3. While Controller Condition : `${__BeanShell(${flow}==true,)}`. This will run for single loop only, as `${flow}` will be set to false in JSR223 Post Processor
   [image]
4. JSR223 Post Processor inside second Sampler under While Controller. Put the following code in script area. This is how you can access the ArrayList

   ```
   ArrayList result = vars.getObject("List");
   for (String value : result) {
   log.info("Values are : " + value);
   }
   vars.put("flow", "false");
   ```

   [image]
5. Result
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your Groovy code itself:

[image]

Most probably your `JSR223 Pre Processor` is not being executed for some reason, either due to [Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) or missing [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) as PreProcessors cannot be executed without Samplers. Try adding `log.info('something')` at the end of the PreProcessor to ensure that it has been run.